# Working in unity editor but not after the build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I'm a student and I'm creating a visual novel in unity for our thesis. Mostly the code is from [them](http://www.indiana.edu/~gamedev/2015/09/27/creating-a-visual-novel-in-unity/) but I studied it and make some revisions to make it mine.

My problem is that everything is working in unity editor, the dialogues are changing and I can choose a decision by clicking a button, but when I try to build it there's nothing except the background.

[This is what it looks like in Unity Editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiYsJ.png)

After the build and I run it in windows, The start() function is working, but when I start to press any key, it won't update as you can see below:

[This what it looks like after I built and run the game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZozN.png)

This is the code in my start() and update() function:

PS: The Input.TouchCount there is to make the game runnable in android too but I want the game run in windows first. Thank you for you help!

**DialogueManager.cs**:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DialogueManager : MonoBehaviour {
DialogueParser parser;

public string dialogue, characterName;
public int lineNum;
int pose;
public int background;
string position;
string[] options;
public bool playerTalking;
List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();

public Text dialogueBox;
public Text nameBox;
public GameObject choiceBox;

void Start () {
    dialogue = "NO! N-NO! PLEASE NO!";
    characterName = "MC";
    pose = 0;
    background = 0;
    position = "MC";
    playerTalking = false;
    parser = GameObject.Find("DialogueParser").GetComponent<DialogueParser>();
    lineNum = 1;
}

void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount >= 1 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began || Input.anyKeyDown && playerTalking == false)
    {
        ShowDialogue();

        lineNum++;
    }

    UpdateUI();
}

public void ShowDialogue()
{
    ResetImages();
    ParseLine();
}

void ResetImages()
{
    if (characterName != "")
    {
        GameObject character = GameObject.Find(characterName);
        SpriteRenderer currSprite = character.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        currSprite.sprite = null;
    }
}

void ParseLine()
{
    if (parser.GetName(lineNum) != "Player")
    {
        playerTalking = false;
        characterName = parser.GetName(lineNum);
        dialogue = parser.GetContent(lineNum);
        pose = parser.GetPose(lineNum);
        background = parser.GetBackground(lineNum);
        position = parser.GetPosition(lineNum);
        DisplayImages();
        DisplayBackground();
    }
    else
    {
        playerTalking = true;
        characterName = "";
        dialogue = "";
        pose = 0;
        background = 1;
        position = "";
        options = parser.GetOptions(lineNum);
        CreateButtons();
    }
}

void DisplayImages()
{
    if (characterName != "")
    {
        GameObject character = GameObject.Find(characterName);

        SetSpritePositions(character);

        SpriteRenderer currSprite = character.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        currSprite.sprite = character.GetComponent<Character>().characterPoses[pose];
    }
}


void SetSpritePositions(GameObject spriteObj)
{
    if (position == "L")
    {
        spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(-2, 0);
    }
    else if (position == "R")
    {
        spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(2, 0);
    }
    else if (position == "Wolf"){
        spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(1, 0);
        spriteObj.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10);
    }
    else if (position == "C")
    {
        spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0);
    }
    else if (position == "MC")
    {
        spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(-5, -3);
    }
    spriteObj.transform.position = new Vector3(spriteObj.transform.position.x, spriteObj.transform.position.y, 0);
}

void DisplayBackground()
{
        GameObject bgObject = GameObject.Find("Background");

        SetBackgroundScale(bgObject);
        bgObject.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0);

        SpriteRenderer currSprite = bgObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        currSprite.sprite = bgObject.GetComponent<Character>().characterPoses[background];
}

void SetBackgroundScale(GameObject bgObject)
{
    if(background == 0)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(17, 18);
    }
    else if(background == 1)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 10, -10);
    }
    else if(background == 2)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(20, 25);
    }
    else if (background == 3)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 18);
    }
    else if (background == 4)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(10, 14);
    }
    else if (background == 5)
    {
        bgObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(15, 18);
    }
}

void CreateButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    {
        GameObject button = (GameObject)Instantiate(choiceBox);
        Button b = button.GetComponent<Button>();
        ChoiceButton cb = button.GetComponent<ChoiceButton>();
        cb.SetText(options[i].Split(':')[0]);
        cb.option = options[i].Split(':')[1];
        cb.box = this;
        b.transform.SetParent(this.transform);
        b.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, -25 + (i * 50));
        b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);
        if (button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text == "")
        {
            b.image.color = new Color(0,0,0,0);
            b.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, -25 + (i * 50));
            b.transform.localScale = new Vector3(20, 20);
        }
        buttons.Add(b);
    }
}

void UpdateUI()
{
    if (!playerTalking)
    {
        ClearButtons();
    }
    dialogueBox.text = dialogue;
    if (characterName == "Wolf")
    {
        nameBox.text = "";
    }
    else nameBox.text = characterName;
}

void ClearButtons()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        print("Clearing buttons");
        Button b = buttons[i];
        buttons.Remove(b);
        Destroy(b.gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

**DialogueParser.cs**:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DialogueParser : MonoBehaviour {

    List<DialogueLine> lines;

struct DialogueLine
{
    public string name;
    public string content;
    public int pose;
    public int background;
    public string position;
    public string[] options;

    public DialogueLine(string Name, string Content, int Pose,int bg, string Position)
    {
        name = Name;
        content = Content;
        pose = Pose;
        background = bg;
        position = Position;
        options = new string[0];
    }
}

void Start () {
    string file = "Assets/Resources/Dialogue/Dialogue";
    string sceneNum = UnityEngine.SceneManagement.SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name;
    sceneNum = Regex.Replace(sceneNum, "[^0-9]", "");
    file += sceneNum;
    file += ".txt";

    lines = new List<DialogueLine>();

    LoadDialogue(file);
}

void Update () {

}

void LoadDialogue(string filename)
{
    string line;
    StreamReader r = new StreamReader(filename);

    using (r)
    {
        do
        {
            line = r.ReadLine();
            if (line != null)
            {
                string[] lineData = line.Split('|');
                if (lineData[0] == "Player")
                {
                    DialogueLine lineEntry = new DialogueLine(lineData[0], "", 0,0, "");
                    lineEntry.options = new string[lineData.Length - 1];
                    for (int i = 1; i < lineData.Length; i++)
                    {
                        lineEntry.options[i - 1] = lineData[i];
                    }
                    lines.Add(lineEntry);
                }
                else
                {
                    DialogueLine lineEntry = new DialogueLine(lineData[0], lineData[1], int.Parse(lineData[2]), int.Parse(lineData[3]), lineData[4]);
                    lines.Add(lineEntry);
                }
            }
        }
        while (line != null);
        r.Close();
    }
}

public string GetPosition(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].position;
    }
    return "";
}

public string GetName(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].name;
    }
    return "";
}

public string GetContent(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].content;
    }
    return "";
}

public int GetPose(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].pose;
    }
    return 0;
}

public int GetBackground(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].background;
    }
    return 0;
}

public string[] GetOptions(int lineNumber)
{
    if (lineNumber < lines.Count)
    {
        return lines[lineNumber].options;
    }
    return new string[0];
}
}
```

PS: DialogueManager.cs is to manage the dialogue, the character images, the characters' name, and showing them in the scene. While the DialogueParser.cs is parsing the line (for example: "MC|"SOMEONE…! HELP! HELP ME!!!"|0|0|R"). The first part is the name, the second is the dialogue, the two numbers are character image and background respectively, and the fifth and last part is the position of a character image. These five parts are separated by "|". In other words, the DialogueParser.cs work is to separate them and give them to DialogueManager.cs.

Comment: The problem is not in this part of the code for sure. Just a tip use getters/setters and don't access the fields like that. Add the entire script so we can help you.

Comment: @IvanKaloyanov I'm done putting the entire script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be in your LoadDialogue function. In Unity, when you make a build, the resources folder is packaged up and therefore "Assets/Resources/Dialogue/Dialogue#.txt" will not exist.

You can read the file using [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html). Note, with Resources.Load you do not need the file extension.

```
TextAsset dialogueAsset = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Dialogue/Dialogue#");
string dialogue = dialogueAsset.text; // This is your whole dialogue file.
```